# How to Apply style to an element present in Grand Parent Component from Child Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, sass

### grand-parent.component.html

## Grand Parent

### parent.component.html

## Parent

### child.component.html

## Child Component

how to apply style to h1 tag present in grand parent.component.html from child.component.scss?

Comment: There is no direct way because it would create a very tight coupling between two components and be a source of hard to identify bugs. You just emit an event from child to parent, then parent to grandparent, and handle it accordingly.

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, you hack your own way of doing it. One method is emitting event as mentioned above, else use a service that toggles a behavior subject or some variable that is subscribed by grandparent component for value changes and update style accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

assume we h1 in grant:

```
<h1 id="grant-h1">HELLO in Grant</h1>
```

you can use this in your ts file in child:

```
const grantH1 = document.getElementById('grant-h1');
(grantH1 as HTMLElement).style.color = 'red';
```

or use this in css file in child:

```
::ng-deep #grant-h1 {
   color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: ng-deep will be used for styling child component from it's ancestor components

Comment: no it's not true. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-556inj?file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.css